# how to get lac/sac using AT Command in python

Tags: python, linux

Hi I have to write a python script to get lac/sac using AT Command. I used the script like to get the IMSI number from a Dongle connected to serial port in Winodws machine.

```
ser.write('AT+CGSN' + '\r\n')
out = ''
time.sleep(1)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += ser.read(1)

print ("IMEI:" + out)
```

When I replace the command with AT+CREG? The output is showing ERROR , something like this:::
OutPut: ERROR

How can I overcome this thing.